# Calculating the "odds in"...

Tags: probability, statistics

If I say to someone, "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100, try and guess it". Their first guess will have a 1 in 100 chance of being correct.

If I say to someone, "I'm thinking of TWO numbers between 1 and 100, try and guess ONE of them". Their first guess will have a 2 in 100 chance of being correct.

Now to my problem: If I'm thinking of 2,500,000 answers out of a possible pool of 342,014,000 guesses - what's the chance of someone correctly guessing ONE of them on their first go? The answer should be in "1 in a ..." format.

And how did you calculate that?

I thought it was:

$${2,500,000} \over {342,014,000}$$

But this gives me `0.007309`, which seems to suggest 1 in 7309. This seems far too low, so I'm assuming I've made a mistake.

My math-starved, flu-addled brain is completely incapable of providing me with an answer!

Comment: When you say 2,500,000 different answers out of a pool of 342,014,000 do u mean, what are the chances that the person will guess the exact set of 2,500,000 numbers you are thinking of? if so then can use the choose function, however the chances will be slim, imagine the lottery, guessing 6 numbers out 31 is already pretty rare so the chances of guessing 2,500,000 out of 342,014,000 is even slimmer.

Comment: @Dphan I mean exactly the same as with the first example: There is one possible answer out of 100. With the second example, there are 2.5m possible correct answers out of 342,014,000 possible guesses. I'll try and make it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the question is to express the ratio
$$R={2,500,000 \over 342,014,000}$$
as some odds $1{:}n$ for a given $n$. You correctly compute a decimal approximated value of $R$, found $R\approx0.007309$, and then (somewhat oddly) suggest that this means that $R$ coincides with the odds
$$
1{:}7309.
$$
Actually, no. The odds $1{:}7309$ correspond to the ratio $\dfrac1{7309}$, which is a little more than $0.0001368$, and not at all $0.007309$.

To express $R$ as $1{:}n$, compute
$$
\frac1R={342,014,000\over 2,500,000}={171,007\over 1,250}.
$$
The ratio on the RHS cannot be further simplified hence there is no integer $n$ such that $R$ is $1{:}n$ and the best one can do is to find some $n$ such that $R$ is *approximately* $1{:}n$. Here,
$$
{171,007\over 1,250}=136.8056,
$$
hence the best answer is that $R$ is approximately $1{:}137$.

Comment: Woah. There's an approximate 1 in 137 chance of guessing correctly...? I understand your maths (I think) and I'm shocked by that answer.

Comment: Forget the millions... If you had 2 correct answers out of a possible pool of 342 guesses, what would you say the odds are? About 1:171, perhaps? And with 3 correct answers out of a possible pool of 342 guesses? About 1:114, perhaps? Well, the true answer is inbetween...

Comment: Yikes. Thanks for explaining that to me. I never would have thought it could have been so high.

Comment: So, in short, I just divided 250000/342,014,000 instead of 342,014,000/250000?

Comment: Yes (replacing 250,000 in your comment by 2,500,000).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the choose function:
$${342,014,000 \choose 2,500,000} = {342,014,000! \over 2,500,000! (342,014,000 - 2,500,000)!}$$ $\approx 1:2.6327541586297393488827821867597485706858490 × 10^{6422014}$

Comment: $n!$ is n factorial. ($1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots\cdot n-1 \cdot n$)

You can read more about the choose function [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: Thanks. All I get is an error in my scientific calculator :-(

Comment: That would be an overflow error. $342,014,000$ needs 29 bits, and factorials grow very quickly. Wolfram Alpha gives the approximation $2.6327541586297393488827821867597485706858490 × 10^{6422014}$

Comment: I think there was some confusion in my original question. I since edited it. Sorry.